# Is it possible to save a PDF attachment back to an email in Outlook?

Tags: c#, email, pdf, outlook, attachment

Can a pdf attachment be opened from outlook, edited, and then saved back to the original email? In other words, edit the copy in the email and not a local downloaded copy. Of course I can store the pdf in a folder and link to it (I'm generating the emails with the pdf attachments), but thought I would ask in case there is a simple way to save back to the email that I may have missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never been able to do this with any sort of attachment, whether it be a PDF or other document.  The closest I've come to doing something like this is for Office documents, where I open from the email, make modifications, then send via email directly from the Office toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

No I dont think this can be done for PDF with out putting the file on the local system.